# ExecJS Unexpected token: operator (>) in vue.js method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, vue.js, execjs, vue-resource

I am having this method in my vue object:

```
  fetchStates: function () {
    this.$http.get('/api/locations/all_states').then((response) => {
      states = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).states
      this.$set('states', states)
    }).then(() => {
      $('.cs-select').trigger('chosen:updated')
    })
  },
```

during assets precompiling I get this error:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 62960, col: 69, pos: 1897152)
```

I managed to locate where this comes from, `.then((response) => {`, but no idea how to fix this. May be ExecJS doesn't know about [promises](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md) syntax in vue-resource. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for those who'll have the same issue, this is were my problem was, it should be `.then(function(response) {` instead of `.then((response) => {`

```
  fetchStates: function () {
    this.$http.get('/api/locations/all_states').then(function(response) {
      states = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).states
      paymentInfo.$set('states', states)
    }).then(function() {
      $('.cs-select').trigger('chosen:updated')
    })
  },
```

Comment: This is interesting, i've had a similar issue, where the same code with the '=>' syntax worked in desktop and android, but didn't work in iOS. So i debugged it on iOS and i got the same exception like yours - "Unexpected token: operator (>)". I'm not sure about it, but i think the '=>' is a js6 standard and maybe it's still not fully supported. If you know more information about this i'd love to hear. In the mean time, your solution worked for me as well +1.

Comment: @ItaiSpector "i think the '=>' is a js6 " this is exactly what it was, I took that from a blog post that, as I found out later, it was using js6 syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tough I was more interested to know if it was related to support issues, it's yet interesting to know if js6 is widely fully supported or no, and when it is expected to get full support. It's probably out there in the web, just have to do a little googling, take care

Comment: @ItaiSpector here I am in 2017 :) yes, it was most certainly a browser support of js6. As for support of j6 in browsers you can find more here - https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/